# Android Studio 1.0RC4 Gradle build error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I just downloaded Android Studio 1.0RC4 and I can't build any project, even newly created ones.

The error I got is:

> **Error:Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip'.**

I was able to download the zip from the browser but it's not working on AS. This is my build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Module build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "simple.com.car10"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Graddle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

I Tried to run graddle - build from cmd, and I got this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Build file 'C:\Users\Giovanni\uild' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Total time: 3.093 secs

JDK: 1.8.0_05

When I hit try again nothing happens, I already tried uninstalling everything and installing again but it didn't work.

Any ideas guys? Thanks.

Comment: This is general Gradle file. Post the one with the name of your module.

Comment: edited with the app graddle

Comment: can you show your gradle-wrapper.properties file?

Comment: Nothing strange in the files. Did you set the SDK path correctly? What JDK are you using?

Comment: Edited with wrapper and jdk version, SDK is set correctly.

Comment: does gradle work on the commandline using "gradlew.bat --gui" on windows or "gradle --gui" on linux

Comment: Yes, gradle.bat -gui works fine

Comment: That "Could not run build action" error message is a generic failure message. You should see more output in the Gradle console; can you add that to your question?

Comment: use buildToolsVersion 21.1.1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I finally got it working guys

I had to **delete** the **.gradle** folder in **'C:\Users\Username\'** and then I opened AS with admin rights and it came back to life!

Thanks everyone.

Comment: For the *NIX user, remove the directory under $HOME/.gradle, then restart Android studio.

Comment: If you have x64 bit Intelli J then  you must have x64 bit java with JAVA_HOME set to it and a _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true set for some reason it has problem with ipv6. sucks

Comment: It's enough removing the caches folder inside the .gradle one and restarting Android Studio with admin rights. Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: Same error on Mac Yosemite. Have deleted everything in site - reinstalled multiple times. Always get: 

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 

The log says: 

2016-04-11 18:40:45,569 [  13180]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle for project 'My Application' failed: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle installation '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10'.

Answer (score 2):

you can probably drop the RC-1 in your build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

Here's a checklist of things that have changed recently

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0

Answer (score 0):

For 64 bit Windows 7, I had to download jdk7 64bit in addition to deleting the .gradle and starting Android studio as an admin. I had also set `JAVA_HOME` to 64bit JDK and set **`JAVA_OPTIONS`** to `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`