# Android Studio update -Error:Could not run build action using Gradle distribution

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have recently updated android studio to the latest version,but then comes the problem.

**Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed.
Error:Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip'.**

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27357918/android-studio-1-0rc4-gradle-build-error) in StackOverflow

However trying everything nothing works - cannot create new project of import anything at the moment.Please kindly advice.

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'  

  android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

     defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sclick.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    task assemble{}
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}

      **Top Level Gradle.build**
```

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all 
           sub-projects/modules.

```
      buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }


    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
  #Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

Comment: See if you have a `.gradle` subdirectory in the project. If yes, close the project in Android Studio, delete the `.gradle` directory, and re-open the project.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have followed your suggestions but its keep on throwing :Error:Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

Comment: Do Build->Clean Project. Hopefully that helps

Comment: @SomCollection--Let us know if MDragon00 (or you or anyone else) solved the problem you were having or if it still persists, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 44):

I had same issue. I have tried many things but nothing worked Until I try following:

1. Close Android Studio
2. Delete any directory matching `gradle-[version]-all` within `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\wrapper\dists\`. If you encounter a "File in use" error (or similar), terminate any running Java executables.
3. Open Android Studio as Administrator.
4. Try to sync project files.
5. If the above does not work, try restarting your computer and/or delete the project's `.gradle` directory.
6. Open the problem project and trigger a Gradle sync.

Comment: I deleted my entire `~/.gradle` folder (on Mac OS  X Yosemite) and the project's `.gradle` folder, rebuilt, and GTG

Comment: This has just worked for me. I restarted my computer, deleted all contents from the `C:\Users\<USER>\.gradle` folder and re-imported the project into AS. After it synced the project files, all worked as normal again.

Comment: As a mac user I can confirm deleting <USER>/.gradle and <PROJECT>/.gradle and then clicking "sync again" works. No need to restart Android Studio.

Comment: This worked for me. I think the cause was a Windows crash during a gradle operation. I had to use an elevated command prompt to rename the.gradle folder (rather than deleting) after closing AS.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar issue, when I upgraded to the latest version of Android Studio 1.3.2. What seemed to work for me was removing the `.gradle` folder from my project directory:

```
rm -rf ~/project/.gradle
```

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue when first start Android Studio in Window 10, with java jdk 1.8.0_66. The solution that worked is:

**Step 1:** Close Android Studio

**Step 2:** Delete Folder C:\Users\Anna\.gradle
(Anna is my username)

**Step 3:** Open Android Studio as Administrator

**Step 4:** If you are currently in an opened project, close current project by select File > Close Project.

**Step 5:** Now you seeing this Quick Start GUI: 
[image: Android Studio Quick Start]

### Select Open an existing Android Studio project, navigate to your project folder and select it.

Wait for gradle to build again (it would download all the dependency in your build.gradle for every module in your project)

If it has not worked till now, you could restart your computer. Do step 1 again.

This happens sometime when I changed Android Studio version or recently upgrade Window. Hope that helps !

Comment: Thanks! This happens when you downloaded an old Android project from GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

I forced to use a proxy and also forced to add proxy setting on gradle.properties as these:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=1080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=1080
```

And also forced to close and open `studio64.exe` as administrator .
Now its all seems greate

Event log says

```
8:21:39 AM Platform and Plugin Updates: The following components are ready to update: Android Support Repository, Google Repository, Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer), Android SDK Platform-Tools 24, Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android SDK Tools 25.1.7
8:21:40 AM Gradle sync started
8:22:03 AM Gradle sync completed
8:22:04 AM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
8:22:25 AM Gradle build finished in 21s 607ms
```

I'm using android studio 2.1.2 downloaded as exe setup file. it has its Gradle ( I also forced to use custom install to address the Gradle )

Comment: Thx, worked for me (I'm on Mac and don't need to reboot AS)

Comment: So what's happening at 1080 port from my localhost?

Comment: @wonsuc You have to have a proxy client listening for incoming requests at port 1080 for example.

Answer (score 2):

Go on Project->Settings->Compiler(Gradle-based android project), find the text field "VM option" and put there:

-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

This shouls solve the issue in any case the error shown in the gradle message window is "Could not reserve enough space for object heap"

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can download the gradle you want from [Gradle Service](https://services.gradle.org/%22gradle%22) by reading the **gradle-wrapper.properties**.Download it ,unpack it where you like and then change your grandle configuration use local not the **recommended**.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I Just  `Invalidate caches/restart`

Answer (score 0):

Try updating gradle dependency to 2.4. For that you need to go to 
`File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Gradle version`.

There you need to change from 2.2.1 to 2.4. Wait for new gradle version to be downloaded.

And you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar problem on Mac.

Looking at the log under Help -> Show logs in Finder I found the following entry.

> You have JVM property "https.proxyHost" set to "127.0.0.1".
> This may lead to incorrect behaviour. Proxy should be set in Settings | HTTP Proxy
> This JVM property is old and its usage is not recommended by Oracle.
> (Note: It could have been assigned by some code dynamically.)

and it turned out I had Charles as a network proxy running. Shutting down Charles solved the problem.