# Android Studio Gradle Sync Falied

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Android Development. Facing issue with gradle. Tried multiple solutions on net but didnt work out changing heap size and all.

Seeing following logs:

```
2016-02-09 00:50:01,621 [  14176]   INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [-Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, /tmp/asLocalRepo0.gradle, --init-script, /tmp/ijinit0.gradle] 
2016-02-09 00:50:06,475 [  19030]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle installation '/opt/android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.8'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
```

Comment: How did you run Gradle? From Android Studio or the command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio update -Error:Could not run build action using Gradle distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589336/android-studio-update-errorcould-not-run-build-action-using-gradle-distributio)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. from android studio

Comment: I tried above solutions mentiioned in your link , didnt work out.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Griffin at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29144520/476796

> Try this:
>
> 1) File -> Invalidate caches / Restart
>
> 2) Shutdown Android Studio
>
> 3) Remove .gradle folder in the user home directory
>
> 4) Restart Android Studio let it download all the Gradle stuff it
>   needs
>
> 5) Gradle build success !
>
> 6) Rebuild project.... success !

If that doesn't work you can also try to check if you are using the correct gradle. You can check this in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Answer (score 0):

Finally trying out of multiple things.
Commenting following lines in the project resolved it.

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize\=512

Can anyone explain how did it help ?