# Android studio error message

Tags: android, android-studio

I have android studio but when I turn on the pop up message: Error:Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip'

I tried this:
Delete c: \ users \ my \ .gradle \ wrapper \ dists \ GRADL-2.2.1-all and then run android studio as administrator. It did not help!

Please help!

Image link:
[1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B57KhqwPWwcIeE9NRXpwWGF6bmc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your question is very confusing as I cant understand what error you are getting etc.. Please upload a screen shot of the error? Worst comes to worst you can just re-install Android studio as I had some issues in the past.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B57KhqwPWwcIMkdnVDhwTHVDYnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B57KhqwPWwcIeE9NRXpwWGF6bmc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you done much on 'MyApplication' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing ~/.gradle, and then reopening android studio, worked for me

see op: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27378213/615533

Answer (score 0):

Update your Gradle and try again:

Link: https://gradle.org/downloads

Comment: Android studio downloading old version Grandle and the same error !

Comment: how u install Grandle?

Comment: are u try unistall AndroidStudio and Install New version?

Comment: I'm offline please to next day